# How to get selected value of datagridview combobox column?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a combox with list of image labels and a save button. On the save button I need to get the combox selected value on the save button if it is null then validate. How I can do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFbsi.png)

This is how I add combox in datagridview:

```
string[] ImageLabels = {Photograph, PassportPage1, PassportPage2, 
PassportPage3, PassportPage4};
var list=new ArrayList();
var combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
combo.HeaderText = "Image Labels";
combo.Name = "combo";
list = new ArrayList();
list.AddRange(ImageLabels);
combo.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
dgvFiles.Columns.Add(combo);
```

I am getting null values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNe0M.png)

Comment: means your datagridview column is of type combobox and you want that combobox selected value  right?

Comment: which event did u used to get values inside `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` ?

Comment: yes datagridview column is of type combobox and i want that combobox selected value.

Comment: on the form_load event i am filling the combobox values

Comment: did u used any event to get values inside that combobox that code u show in second image

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below event for your `datagridview`

Here my datagridview name is `dataGridView1`

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string comboboxSelectedValue = string.Empty;

    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn))
        comboboxSelectedValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

**1) dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged:** This event will fire your `dataGridView1_CellValueChanged` immediately after you select value from your `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

**2) dataGridView1_CellValueChanged:** This event will give you the value of your selected option in combobx, we additionally checked that is this the values comes from `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` or not.

You may add above events on `Form1_Load` like

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CellValueChanged +=
             new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
    dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged +=
                 new EventHandler(dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @lightcoder, view the answer might be it help you :)  add events from `Property Window` of your `datagridview` or manually add in `Form1_Load`